# Limit of a sum of two specific diverging sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am supposed to find the limit:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}\right)$

Since we have not spoken about how to calculate the limit of a function in the lecture (only the definition), I have reduced it to a sequence:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(n - \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1})$

Intuitively, it looks like it should go to 0 since you can say $n = n - 1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, but that logic is wrong since the limit is supposed to be $\frac{1}{2}$ (checked on WolframAlpha). I have no idea how to get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with the continue variable $x$, without changing it to $n$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{2}} \right ) = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{2}} \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right ) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-(1-x^{2})}{x^{2}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})} =$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Option:

Set $y^2=1-x^2$ and consider $\lim y \rightarrow 1$.

Numerator: $1-y$.

Denominator: $1-y^2=(1-y)(1+y)$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your sequence with $n$,
apply the usual
conjugation for difference of square roots:

$\begin{array}\\
(n - \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1})
&=(n - \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1})\dfrac{(n + \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1})}{(n + \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1})}\\
&=\dfrac{n^2 - n(n-1)}{n + \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1}}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{n + \sqrt n  \sqrt {n - 1}}\\
&\to \dfrac{n}{2n}\\
&=\dfrac12\\
\end{array}
$